# Batch Variable Range for %TIME%

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, time, range

For school, I would like to be able to create a batch file that will check what the `%TIME%` variable is and if it `8:15-9:45`, then goto my first period folder `9:45-10:30` to goto second period, etc. I know how to do this if there is a specific time, but not how to set a range of time. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to convert the time into HHMMSS format.  Something like this

```
set timep=%time%
if "%timep:~1,1%" == ":" set timep=0%timep%
set timeval=%timep:~0,2%%timep:~3,2%%timep:~5,2%
```

Now set the default period to 0

```
set /a period=0
```

Since in string form 083000 is between 081500 and 094500, you can just stick to string comparisons without converting to numeric

```
...
if /i %timeval% geq 103000 set /a period=%period%+1
if /i %timeval% geq 094500 set /a period=%period%+1
if /i %timeval% geq 081500 set /a period=%period%+1
```

%period% will now hold 0 if the time is less than 0815, 1 if it is between 0815 and 0945 etc.

Comment: This depends on the time format in regional settings showing a 24 hour clock, right?  A 12 hour clock will not sort for a full 24 hours.

Comment: Yes, true however I believe that Windows's clock in the lower left hand corner can be changed from 12 to 24 HR clock, but the variable "%TIME%" is always 24 hour.

Comment: I've just tested it by switching regions and formats - %time% is 24 hour.